# Get all column entries for each unique id in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table structured something like this:

```
profile   |  tag
-------------------------
p1        | tag1
p1        | tag2
p1        | tag3
p2        | tag1
p2        | tag3
```

I want to run a query that returns something like:

```
tag1, tag2, tag3
tag1, tag3
```

Basically, for each unique profile, a list of the tags that exist in the table.

Is that possible, or do I need to have a unique column in my result for each tag I care about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns what you want:

```
SELECT array_agg(tag)
FROM table1
GROUP BY profile
```

Or :

```
SELECT string_agg(tag, ',')
FROM table1
GROUP BY profile
```

`string_agg` let's you specify what delimiter you want and ORDER the results in each row.

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b807e/11)</kbd>

Comment: or `select profile, array_to_string(array_agg(tag), ', ')`. +1

Comment: `string_agg(tag, ',')` is probably better